# Bad line wrapping in title when editing a question

Tags: bug, status-completed

I edited a question and noticed the wrapping of the title on the edit screen was a bit odd. Have a look at the screenshot; the word 'two' is split after the 't'.

I resized my browser window, which only moved the problem to different parts of the title.

[image: Bad word wrapping]

Do 'we' have the ability to fix things like this, or is this likely to be a general Stack Exchange problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [general problem, reported on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318655/on-sites-with-new-responsive-theme-word-wrap-on-long-titles-breaks-in-the-middl). My reading is that there is a fix planned to go out already.